# How to download file using Express?

Tags: node.js, express, download, microservices

I am having a curious problem where a download request from the browser will be passed onto a microservice via the Express layer that serves the frontend. The service queries the db, and generates a csv on the fly and can stream it.

Right now, I am fetching the file to my Express server, and then streaming it to the browser.

Is there a way I can directly pipe the file to the browser without exposing the micro-service endpoint ?

Comment: The answer is yes.  If you wanted a better answer than that, you should ask a better question with some details and code showing what you have so far.

Comment: I have no idea on how to even start doing this redirection of stream from a secure service to an unsecure environment.Hence I have no samples or work that I can share. It would be great if you can help me with keywords that I can google for.

Comment: You can just `.pipe()` a stream to another stream, but you didn't show us anything yet, so there's nothing for us to tell you.  What exactly *is* this micro-service, and how do you call it?  Not all this stuff even uses HTTP, we have no idea what you're doing right now.  Much more context is needed.

Comment: `streams` and `pipe` .. now I know what to look for. Thanks @Brad ..